# Gradle:How to copy respective manifestfile to product flavors

Tags: android, gradle

I have two product flavors like:

```
productFlavors{
    honda {
        packageName "com.test.android.app"
    }       
    phone {
        packageName "com.test.android.app"
    }    
}
```

I have a manifest folder structure like:

```
honda/AndroidManifest.xml

phone/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Now, I have to copy (by using Task Copy, if possible) `honda` manifest to `honda` flavor and `phone` manifest to `phone` flavor.

How to achieve this? thanks in advance

Comment: "Now,i have to copy (by using Task Copy, if possible) honda manifest to honda flavor and phone manifest to phone flavor." -- why do you think that you need this? Put the common manifest elements in `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, and put the flavor-specific elements in the flavors' editions of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: yes that can be done, but i'm wondering whether we could copy respective manifest files

Comment: What makes you think that copying will give you a better and/or more-maintainable solution?

Comment: main idea is to avoid changing in main/manifest file but in respective manifest file while developing. Eventually, copy respective manifest to respective flavor and build.